# What is the easiest way to learn ActionScript when you know JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I am an Ajax developer and I want to build a Flash application. Given my previous experience with JavaScript, what do you thing will be the easiest way to learn ActionScript and what are the obstacles I might encounter?

Answer (score 5):

Don't whatever you do start by buying Flash Pro. It is a designer tool and is really rather crap for developing code. By all means invest in it later, but it is a hindrance to coders getting into ActionScript; not an aid. I'd recommend getting yourself either [Flex Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/features/flex_builder/) if you can afford it, or an open source ActionScript IDE like [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/) if not.

Then grab yourself a couple of books on ActionScript and/ or Flex and start reading. Also it is worth downloading any examples of simple Flash apps you can find that include code in order to learn how others do things.

Something to bear in mind when moving from JavaScript to ActionScript is that AS1 was very JavaScript-like, AS2 was less so, and there is little similarity between JavaScript and AS3. Thus if you have the time and inclination, try and pick up a cheap copy of an AS1 and AS2 book and skim through them first to understand the language's history. You'll likely get into AS3 far faster that way. Of course if you are aware of ECMAScript v4 (which will likely now never see the light of day), then you can jump straight to AS3 with confidence.

Answer (score 4):

My advice would be to download a copy of FlexBuilder and stick to AS3.
AS1 and AS2 are now irrelevant and not used to develop "Flash application" anymore.
don't waste your time reading about it, it might confuse you.

There are a lot of resources available to learn Flex, just google it.
The best book i had to read about the subject is [Essential ActionScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526946) by Colin Moock.
It is a reference

But most of all, code, code and code again.

You might try to port some of your previous projects as a good learning exercise.

Good luck with your learning.

Comment: >AS1 and AS2 are now irrelevant<
You try telling that to all those poor poor colleagues of mine developing mobile phone content  in japan!  it's awful!

Comment: My answer is Essential Actionscript. The book is a gold mine. Front to back, and you will have made the transition.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to learn action script can only through video tutorials. Better tryout video tutorials which helps u lot teach you step by step (very easily understandable) which is very easy to understand. you can also vist http://www.infoclassi.do.am for all video tutorials. You can also order them if you need any other tutorials at less cost when compared to other tutorials with the same quality.